# How do you chain pages in Nightwatch JS?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to use nightwatch.js to 1. login to my app, and 2. test a page there. I've setup my login steps as a page, which works well, but after they execute, the steps to navigate to my page and test it are never executed. If I try to execute the page first, it can be navigated to, but I need the login to test it. Is it just not possible to go from page to page in nightwatch?

Login:

```
const loginCommands = {
login() {
    return this
        .waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
        .setValue('@emailInput', config.email)
        .setValue('@passInput', config.password)
        .waitForElementVisible('@loginButton')
        .click('@loginButton');
    },
};

module.exports = {
url: loginUrl,
commands: [loginCommands],
elements: {
    emailInput: {
        selector: 'input[name=email]',
    },
    passInput: {
        selector: 'input[name=password]',
    },
    loginButton: {
        selector: 'button[type=submit]',
    },
},
};
```

Page:

```
const pageCommands = {
navigateToTab() {
    return this
        .waitForElementVisible('@tabOne')
        .click('@tabOne')
},
};

module.exports = {
url: pageUrl,
commands: [pageCommands],
elements: {
    tabOne: {
        selector: 'a[id="tab-one]',
    }
},
};
```

Test:

```
    'test page': function (browser) {
    const loginPage = browser.page.login();
    loginPage
        .navigate()
        .login();
    const callPage = browser.page.callPage();
    callPage
        .navigate()
        .navigateToTab();
    browser.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle, but now i think i've found the solution.
This one will change a bit the way of writing your tests but will do the job, please take a look at the next repository:

[Nightwatch POM done right :)](https://github.com/Eseoghene/Nightwatch-POM/blob/master/tests/test1.js)